# Add scroll to all rows in a table except for the first

Tags: html, css

I have a page with:
1 - header.
2 - table.
3 - footer.

The table has a **first row which is like a title for each column**. After that, all the data gets ordered by row and column.

I need to scroll all the rows except the first one in the top. I try and try and I got a headache.

This is the start position: [Demo](http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/a/temp.html)

And this is One of my attempts: [Demo1](http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/temp.html)

Comment: hint: `position: fixed;`

Comment: Perhaps it is possible but is it the right solution?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/66-table-styling-2-fixed-header-and-highlighting/

Answer (score 0):

I can think a few solutions..

One would be using two tables, pulling the headers out and placing the lower part of the table in a div that you can scroll.

Second could be using waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)to lock the table header in and target it with tr:first-child

A third could be using an image as the header and scrolling the content in it's own div tag.

(using position:fixed will keep something locked on a page in position)

Hope these help :)